# Simple HTML Search Box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to be able to create a text field for a user to type in a page name, click a button, and get directed to the page.  For example, the user inputs projects in the box, it needs to direct them to the projects page of my website.  How would I go about doing this?  I am new to HTML and I have searched for a solution for a while.  Thanks!

Comment: Please show some effort when asking for guidance.  Include specific examples.  This is pretty much the basics of any form so searching for HTML and form will likely give you your example.  The "Submit" section of this page might help, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.

Comment: Try a search for "implementing search on your website". Search is not a trivial subject or easily answered, and there are many approaches which all depend on what technologies you have in mind (server-side scripting, javascript only, etc) and how robust of a solution you want (auto-corretion, plural-form simplification/expansion, file name versus file content searching, etc). As it is, is your question is too broad to answer as there are whole books dedicated to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

You can use this one (from Google Custom Search), it is very easy for use, since you are new in this field.

http://www.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bit of code to get you started if you want to code something yourself. I personally like to use tools like jquery for building javascript but here is some straight up javascript code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToProject(){
        var project = document.getElementById("project").value;
        window.location.href = "http://mysite.com/"+project;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="project"/>
    <button id="submit" onclick="goToProject()">Go</button>
</form>
</body>
```